# Elasticsearch compare long sequence strings with fuzzy query

Tags: elasticsearch, sequence, fuzzy-search

I have two long String sequences that are similar:

```
C50FD711C2C43287351892A4D82F44B055F048C46D2C54197AC1D1E921F11E6699C4057C4B93907518E6DCA51A672D3D3E419160DAE276CB7716D11B94D8C3BB2E4A591329B7AF973D17A7F9336342FFAAFD4D
```

and

```
C50FD711C2C43287351892A4D820B5EAC5F048C1E67CAC197AC1D1E921F11C3623C1DCD6493907518E6DCA18CD71016E7FD1160DAE276CB7716D11B94A6B762E4A591329B7AF973D17A7F9336342FFAAFD4D
```

Its distance is 41.
I would like to find those strings that are similar to eachother. I started a query like this:

```
GET my_index/_type/_search
{
"query": {
        "fuzzy" : {
            "sequence.keyword": {
                "value": "C50FD711C2C43287351892A4D820B5EAC5F048C1E67CAC197AC1D1E921F11C3623C1DCD6493907518E6DCA18CD71016E7FD1160DAE276CB7716D11B94A6B762E4A591329B7AF973D17A7F9336342FFAAFD4D",
                "boost": 1.0,
                "fuzziness": 50,
                "prefix_length": 10,
                "max_expansions": 200
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried with sequence.keyword and sequence, the field is of type text and type keyword.
However, it did not find the other similar sequence string in my index. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is pretty simple. The maximum edit distance that is allowed is 2 (as can be seen in the [source code for the `Fuzziness` class](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/2d6c46255cd3f642ddbf18fa55e2fad194fc01b6/server/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/common/unit/Fuzziness.java#L196)

You can try with a simpler value, if you index `AAAAAA` and try to search for `AAABBB` with `fuzziness: 3`, you'll get nothing.

Comment: ok thanks for the answer, why did they not allow more? Because it would take too long to compage documents then? And are there elasticsearch APIs for Node.js that are allowed to search for bigger edit distance? Or would I have to implement an own levenshtein distance (or from some library) and compare each document manually with each other then?

Comment: Allowing for more edit distance [would kill relevance](). I'm using the [`fast-levenshtein`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fast-levenshtein) node.js library and that works pretty well. No need for ES to do that.

Comment: ok I will try that out thanks, maybe one more question: Can you tell me if this is practicable if you want to compare about 200000 documents or even more (~2million) with this library, if you have to do n*(n-1) /2  comparisons? And how long would this take ?

Comment: I have absolutely no idea, it depends on many factors, your hardware being one. Do you need to compare one value against 200K or each of the 200K values with each other?

Comment: I have to compare each of the 200K values with each other. Because I want to find duplicates of documents. Those documents have a minhash Hashkey ( based on the hashed content) that is similar for similar documents.

Comment: ok but that means that if edit distance >= 1, then the hash is different, which means the content is different, which implies that they are not duplicates, right?

Comment: yeah, but the thing is, that minhash calculates a similar hash value for similar documents, means similar documents can have several edit-distances in difference in their hash-values. And I want to query for that distance (more than 2). The hashvalue is a long 160 char string (and build from the "minhash" algorithm..).

Comment: ok, too bad, it would have been easy otherwise, using a terms aggregation and min_doc_count = 2...

Comment: yeah I know but that I already tried out...and I recognized Elasticsearch is extremely fast on comparing 200k documents on that string with edit distance 2... too bad it doesn't work with bigger distance